# Как отслеживать состояние сервиса на VDS?

Tags: ubuntu, vds, systemctl

После перезапсуска сервиса **my_servis**:

```
sudo systemctl restart my_servis
```

Можно посмотреть его состояние:

```
sudo systemctl status my_servis
```

Но проблема в том, что он будет отображать только последние 10 строчек.

В докере, например, можно запустить контейнер с параметром: **-d** и тогда можно смотреть прям в реальном времени что происходит, можно ли такое же провернуть и с сервисом на VDS?

Если нет, то может можно поправить какой-нибудь конфиг для увеличения количества строк?

Comment: Ну, [journalctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/Journal_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))?

Comment: @andreymal, а если несколько сервисов запущено? Сейчас через него видно только результат по основному порту, а если есть сервис, который работает на другом порту, то как его посмотреть?

Comment: Аргумент `-u` можно указывать несколько раз (а при чём тут порты — непонятно)

Comment: @andreymal, как посмотреть за последние 5 минут? Вот так не работает: **journalctl -u NAME_SERVICE --since "5 min ago"**

Comment: Почему не работает? Лично у меня работает

Comment: @andreymal, хм.. действительно работает, просто не посмотрел, что за последние 5 минут никаких действий не было.